# Failed to load platform rendering library

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I've installed Android studio 1.4 and installed `SDK` correctly but when i started the new project as in the tutorial everything worked fine but the device image didn't appeared in the middle as in the tutorial and `Failed to load platform rendering library` is showing. What is the problem?

This is start screen of my project.
[Start Screen of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy4ih.png)

This is when i run the project.
[Android Project Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eanp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the Android version to render layouts in IDE from 26 to some lower version.